# typeahead.js can't find the styling to modify it OR can I override an html elements style from css?

Tags: css, typeahead.js

typeahead.js is one file but for some reason, it adds html elements that have 'style' attributes and I am trying to fix a z-index but it's defined in type-ahead generated element here.  I don't see styling defined in typeahead.js though.  How do I override this highlighted thing to be z-index=9999999 since some elements in this theme are 99999 (annoying)

[image]

We are trying to move the menu above some buttons but I don't know how to modify typeahead's generated html.  Why do they not use css here with a typeahead.css file?  It seems kind of weird.

thanks,
Dean

Found this project(https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js) a fork and upgrading to 1.3.1 has same issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some built-in class names (undocumented, if I recall) you can use to override the default styles. Here's an example from one of my projects. I think the `tt-menu` class is the one you want. It controls the overall pop-up menu as a whole.

```
/*****************************
 * Twitter Typeahead Styling *
 *****************************/
.twitter-typeahead {
    width: 100%;
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999;
}

.tt-menu {
  width: 422px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}
```

Changing the generated HTML would require forking the project, modifying the code, and then using your custom-built version. It's not impossible, but modifying the inner workings of typeahead.js is probably not what you want to get into.

Comment: I thought an elements style attribute was the final override so that doesn't work, correct?  ie. for some reason, typeahead.js is adding an elements style attribute(I wish it didn't).  BTW, thanks for taking over typeahead.js....it rocks!!!! (odd, I can't seem to tag you Jeremy with the @...

Comment: Hmm, yes, the style attribute is harder to override. I didn't see that it was setting that, including the z-index. Try this CSS tricks page: https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/